# Custom Edit Form not showing fields

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, custom-form, rich-text

I have created a custom edit form to a specific list on my site.

This custom form shows all the fields normally to my user, who is a site collection and farm administrator, but the other users have reported that the form is not showing any of the fields.

Testing with these other users, got ​​the following javascript error loading the form:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'UseInlineStyle' of null

One of the fields in my custom form is a "multiple text field" with rich text enabled. When I hide that rich text field from the custom form, no error occurs and all other fields are displayed correctly to any user.

Already checked the permissions of these users and everything is ok , so far they have always used the standard edit form with no problem. Even putting administrator permissions to other users the error persists.

Anyone have any idea? Im using Sharepoint 2013 on-premise.

Thanks.

Comment: what browser are using? Did you try on both Chrome and IE?

Comment: Yes, same problem on both browsers